# Probability of winning a game guessing $k$ random numbers in sequence with optimal strategy

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification, combinations

We are playing a game as follows, suppose we have $k$ spaces. One at a time, we will pick $k$ random integers from the range $[1,n]$, without replacement. After selecting a number, we must choose to place it in one of our spaces before selecting the next number. We "win" if after selecting our $k$ numbers, our sequence on our spaces is in increasing order.

Here is an example of a winning game where $n=10, k=3$.

Initial state: _ _ _

Randomly select $5$, place in middle slot: _ $5$ _

Randomly select $6$, place in last slot: _ $5$ $6$

Randomly select $1$, place in first slot: $1$ $5$ $6$

Note that had the last number been a $7,8,9,10$ instead of $1$, then we would have lost as none of those values are $<5$.

Clearly, if you are just randomly selecting the slot at every iteration, the probability of winning is $\frac{1}{k!}$. However, we can do better by having good strategy; why place a $1$ in the last slot when thats an instant loss, for example.

Define $P(n,k)$ to be the maximum probability of winning the game given $k$ slots and $n$ random numbers. When we say "maximum probability" we mean that whenever we select a random number, we put it in the slot where from there we have the highest probability of winning the game.

---

**Edit:** I have since realized I need more base cases. $P(n,0)=1$ and $P(j,k)=0$ if $j<k$. $P(j, j)=1$

We will prove our formula recursively with induction. Notice that in our base case, $P(n, 1)=1$ for all values of $n$.

Assume that for all values of $m<n$ and $j<k$ that $P(m, j)$ provides the maximum probability of winning for $j$ slots with selection $[1,m]$.

We now define the formula for the $n,k$ case. We have $n$ options for what we can pick as our first number, for the sake of argument suppose we selected the number $x\in[1,n]$. With this first number we can now calculate the probability of winning the $n, k$ case, *given* our first selected number is $x$. Notate this as $P(n,k;x)$[^1]. Since there is a $\frac{1}{n}$ chance of selecting any particular $x$, we know that

$$
P(n,k) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{x=1}^n P(n,k;x)
$$

Now to calculate $P(n,k;x)$, we must determine the optimal location to place $x$ in the slots. If I was to place $x$ in slot $i$, I would partition the board into two sections, one of length $i-1$ on the left, and one of length $k-i$ on the right. In order to win, we must select **exactly** $i-1$ numbers to place on the left that are $<x$, and **exactly** $k-i$ numbers on the right that are $>x$, otherwise we lose as we have placed $x$ in the wrong spot for our selected numbers. The probability of this occuring is
$$
\frac{\binom{x-1}{i-1}\binom{n-x}{k-i}}{\binom{n-1}{k-1}}
$$
However, just getting the correct numbers is not enough, as we must put them in the correct locations, but these partitioned boards are equivilent to playing the same game twice! So if we get valid numbers (per above) we only need to win the partitioned boards in order to win the game. Since $x-1, n-x < n$ and $i-1, k-i<k$ we can use our inductive hypothesis to say that the probability of winning if we place $x$ in slot $i$ is
$$
\frac{\binom{x-1}{i-1}\binom{n-x}{k-i}}{\binom{n-1}{k-1}}P(x-1, i-1)P(n-x, k-i).
$$
In order to optimize our strategy, we select the $i$ for which this value is maximized which gives us
$$
P(n,k;x)=\max_{1\leq i\leq k}\left[\frac{\binom{x-1}{i-1}\binom{n-x}{k-i}}{\binom{n-1}{k-1}}P(x-1, i-1)P(n-x, k-i)\right]
$$

Which means we can sum over all values of $x$ and divide by $n$ to get the value of $P(n,k)$

**Q.E.D.**

---

This recursive formula was also not too tough to program up, here is a plot of when $n=50$, notice that the y axis is a log plot so the variations can be seen. Minimal solution is when $k=35$ with $P(50,35)\approx 3.28\cdot 10^{-5}$

[[image: Plot <span class=]$n=50$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFTI9.jpg)

As an aside, has anyone seen this before? I was thinking of writing this into a blog post for my students and if this is a known thing than I'd like to reference a paper on it

---

[^1]: I understand my notation is starting to get a bit garbo while writing this down

Comment: Interesting.  Without having thought too hard about it, I'd have guessed that the optimal strategy was to divide the $n$ into $k$ "equal" blocks (as close as you can get, anyway).  Then place your selections into the spaces accordingly (again, as best you can).  Well, I guess then it isn't clear how to reset the blocks after the first selection...Is there a natural algorithm?

Comment: Maybe just split the selected block in two and adjoin the stubs to the appropriate block?  Simple, at least.

Comment: I'd imagine that yeah its to take the two partitions and then treat them as their own individual games

Comment: Your solution looks absolutely fine. What I‘d like to know: Is the best move to place the (first) number *exactly* proportional to its value? Eg, up to which value do we best place it in the first field?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen that is an interesting question, I just assumed binning would be the best option as described, but I can make an edit where I make a figure showing optimal placements

Comment: This would be the equivalent problem for $n \to \infty$ https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/583062/qr-interview-problem-guessing-order-of-draws-from-iid-u0-1