Strategy for correctly sorting proceduraly sampled set of numbers
Consider the following single player game. Let $N$ be some natural number. The game then proceeds as follows. On step $1\leq k\leq N$, we sample $X_k\sim\mathcal U([0,1])$ and give it a ranking $1\leq r_k\leq N$. This rank cannot be one that has been previously assigned to some other number. The game ends in a loss at step $k$ if there exist $k_-,k_+<k$ such that $r_{k_-}+1=r_{k_+}$ and $x_{k_-}<x_k<x_{k_+}$, there exists $k_+<k$ with $r_{k_+}=N$ and $x_{k_+}<x_k$, or there exists $k_-<k$ with $r_{k_-}=1$ and $x_{k_-}>x_k$. The game is won if all $N$ steps manage to be completed. My question is then as follows:

What is the optimal strategy for assigning the ranks $r_k$?
Following this optimal strategy, what's the probability we win the game?

It's intuitively clear that $r_1=\lfloor Nx_1\rfloor$, for example, but how about the other samples? ANd how do they react to already sampled points?

From the requirement, it looks like we need to predict the rank and try to arrange them in a descending order - as each ascending pair (with successive rank) will create a losing interval, so we would like to minimize the number of such intervals - or more accurately the union of the lengths of such intervals and try to postpone their appearance as late as possible to minimize the number of affected sample as well. Guess we will need some sort of backward induction from the last step.

If we work for small $N$, $N = 1, 2$ is not sufficient for a losing condition, $N = 3$ is surely winning by unconditionally assigning the the first one with rank $2$, and then assigning the second such that a descending pair will be formed - assign rank $3$ if $X_2 < X_1$, and rank $1$ otherwise. Then no losing interval will be formed so the game will surely win. I think we can begin to consider for $N = 4$ cases.

In general, I think the subsequent assignment problem arise when 1) we have formed descending pair but we sample a value that fall between that descending interval, which means we need to ultimately break the descending sequence and form a ascending pair at some point; 2) we leave empty ranks in the middle but the last few sample are either too large / small and does not fall into those intervals.

@BGM forgot to mention that the edges get blocked as well, so the strategy you mentioned does not work for $N=2,3$. Only $N=1$ is guaranteed a win.

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4670432/683666
